# Iterative algorithm for computing $\Sigma^{1/2} x$

Tags: matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Say I have a PSD matrix $\Sigma$ and a vector $x$, is there an iterative algorithm (faster than computing $\Sigma^{1/2}$ using Cholesky decomposition) for computing  $\Sigma^{1/2} x$?
(In this question, by $\Sigma^{1/2}$ I always just mean some matrix $L$ such that $\Sigma=LL^T$.)

For example, I might use Newton's method:
$
L_{k+1} = \frac12 (L_k + L^{−1}_k \Sigma), L_0 = \Sigma,
$
which converges to $L_{\infty} = \Sigma^{1/2}$.
If applied to a single vector:
\begin{align}
L_{k+1} x = \frac12 (L_k x + L^{−1}_k \Sigma x), L_0 = \Sigma,
\end{align}
I can compute each step in $O(n^2 \sqrt{\kappa})$ time using [Conjugate gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) (where $\kappa$ is the condition number of $L_k$) to compute $L_k^{-1} (\Sigma x)$.

I'm not sure how many iterations of Newton I need (Or Denman-Beavers or some other type of iteration), but I assume it also depends on the condition number somehow.
All in all I can compute $\Sigma^{1/2} x$ in $O(n f(\kappa))$ time.

However, using gradient descent at each step of an iterative method seems silly. I doubt the above method is every competitive with just computing $\Sigma^{1/2}$ using Cholesky.
But I do wonder: *Is there an iterative method to compute $\Sigma^{1/2} x$ fast?*
For example something like the conjugate method (or even Jacobi iteration), but which has as purpose to compute the square root (or inverse square root) rather than the inverse?

(Btw, I should mention that the reason I want to compute $\Sigma^{1/2} x$ is to sample a multivariate normal distribution. If there's a different method to do this in $n^2$ time, I'd also be very interested in that.)

*Update:* According [Computing Aα, log(A) and Related Matrix Functions by Contour Integrals](https://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/834/1/hale_higham_trefethen.pdf) Theorem 2.1, eq. 2.9, there is at least an iterative square root method that only takes $\approx\log(\kappa)$ many iterations, where each iteration requires a linear solve.
That means we can find $\Sigma^{1/2}x$ in $\approx n^2 \sqrt{\kappa} \log(\kappa)$.
Though I'm still curious if you could get just $n^2 \sqrt{\kappa}$ by utilizing that the later linear solves are very close to the previous ones.

Comment: The Cholesky decomposition does not produce the square root. There are many matrices that provide decompositions of the form $Σ=CC^T$, one of them the PSD square root.

Comment: Then I should clarify that I'm interested in computing $Lx$ for any matrix $L$ such that $\Sigma=LL^T$.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The decomposition $\Sigma=LL^T$ is not unique. The values of $Lx$ are therefore not unique in general. If you don't know $L$, how can you possibly compute $Lx$?

Comment: @user1551 I'm just saying I'm interested in an algorithm that computes $Lx$ for any such $L$. Which $L$ is more efficient to target, I don't be the judge over. In my question I give examples for two different $L$, the Cholesky one which takes $\Omega(n^3)$ time to compute, and whichever $L$ Newton's method converges to, which takes $O(n^2 f(\kappa))$ time.

Comment: The question for the algorithm is that you want the same $L$ for  all inputs $x$. That might be hard to guarantee if $L$ is not known explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't need the same $L$ for all inputs $x$. I just have a single input $x$. Can you point me to the sentence that caused this confusion, then I will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the "Newton based" algorithm in my original question doesn't work, since it requires solving a linear system in $L_k$.
But we don't actually keep $L_k$ around, only $L_k x$.
Luckily there is another iterative method that *does work*:
I found this interesting article
[Computing $A^\alpha$
, log(A) and Related Matrix
Functions by Contour Integrals](https://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/1136/1/hht08.pdf).

Translated from Matlab to Python, and specialized to finding the "squareroot-vector-product", it looks like this:

```
def sqrtm_vp(A, x, m=None, M=None, niter=10):
    if m is None or M is None:
        eigs = np.linalg.eig(A)[0]
        m, M = min(eigs), max(eigs)

    Kp = scipy.special.ellipk(1 - m / M)
    t = (0.5 + np.arange(niter)) * Kp / niter
    sn, cn, dn, _ = scipy.special.ellipj(t, 1 - m / M)
    w2 = m * (sn / cn) ** 2
    dzdt = (2 * Kp * np.sqrt(m) / (np.pi * niter)) * dn / cn**2

    d = A.shape[0]
    Sx = np.zeros(d)
    # Could do this in parallel
    for j in range(niter):
        Sx += dzdt[j] * np.linalg.solve(A + w2[j] * np.eye(d), x)
    return A @ Sx
```

The paper provides error bounds on the order of $\exp(-O(N/\log(\kappa)))$, meaning we need just $N=O(\log\kappa)$ iterations, each of which take a single linear solve, which is $O(d^2 \sqrt{\kappa})$ time with conjugate gradient descent.

I still don't know if it's possible to go from $d^2 \sqrt{\kappa}\log{\kappa}$ time to just $d^2 \sqrt{\kappa}$, but at least this is pretty close.